# How do I correctly sort strings in C?

Tags: c, string, sorting

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

int cmp(const void *a, const void *b) {
    const char **ia = (const char **)a;
    const char **ib = (const char **)b;
    return strcmp(*ia, *ib);
}

void print_array(char **array, size_t len) {
    size_t i;
    for(i=0; i<len; i++) {
        printf("%s, ", array[i]);
    }
    putchar('\n');
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

        char *strings[] = { "z1.doc", "z100.doc",  "z2.doc", "z3.doc", "z20.doc"};
        size_t strings_len = sizeof(strings) / sizeof(char *);
        print_array(strings, strings_len);
        qsort(strings, strings_len, sizeof(char *), cmp);
        print_array(strings, strings_len);

        system("PAUSE");
        return 1;
}
```

the actual output is

```
z1.doc, z100.doc, z2.doc, z20.doc, z3.doc
```

and I want it to be

```
z1.doc, z2.doc, z3.doc, z20.doc, z100.doc
```

What am doing wrong?

Comment: Yikes! So many stars! `const char *ia = a;` /* ... */ `return strcmp(ia, ib);`

Comment: Came across this at http://www.mail-archive.com/activeperl@listserv.activestate.com/msg23829.html: Explorer uses the StrCmpLogicalW() function in shlwapi.dll to sort filenames
into "logical" order.  The exact sort order is not guaranteed and may change with each Windows release or service pack!

Comment: @pmg: That's incorrect. Doing it as you suggest will surely result in segmentation fault. The alternative variant would be `const char *ia = *(const char **) a;...; return strcmp(ia, ib);`, but absolutely not what you suggest.

Comment: @AndreyT: it works for me :) [ http://codepad.org/zcFJ4o44 ]

Comment: @pmg: No, it doesn't. You simply failed to test it properly. You are re-interpreting pointer values as C-strings and comparing the resulting "garbage" strings. If it didn't crash for you, it is simply because you got lucky. Run it and take a look at your "sorted" array for a laugh. Then think about what you done. Again, your version makes no sense whatsoever.

Comment: @pmg: Ever wondered why in your output (at the link to codepad) 'z20' follows `z3', while in reality it should be the other way around? :))

Comment: D'oh! What I meant before was: `const char **ia = a;` or, to keep constness correct: `const char *const *ia = a;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your comparator to say:

```
return (atoi(*ib + 1) - atoi(*ia + 1));
```

Comment: that will only work if there is only 1 number in the filename and all the characters are identical.  it won't work properly for "z1aa.doc", "z1zz.doc", "z1bb.doc".  it wont' work for "z10_10.doc" and "z10_5.doc", etc.

Comment: return (atoi(*ia + 1) - atoi(*ib + 1));

Answer (score 4):

The actual output is correct, the string "z100.doc" is less than "z2.doc".  The strcmp compares character by character and when it gets to the '1' that is less than '2' and it stops there, so z100 < z2.

If you name the files z001.doc, z002.doc, z003.doc, z020.doc, z100.doc it will sort the way you want.

Comment: -1 Renaming the files is not the answer to this question. The OP wants to do work for the user, not make the user do (unnecessary) work to get his/her files displayed properly. Anyone who upvotes this doesn't understand the concept of "interface usability" - _no one_ other than us programmers expects lists to be sorted in the order that the standard `strcmp()` sorts in.

Comment: The question was "Why is the sorted output I get not the sorted output I expect, and how can I fix that?"

Answer (score 1):

You want a *natural sorting algorithm* as opposed to the ASCIIbetical sorting algorithm provided by default. See [Jeff's blog entry](https://blog.codinghorror.com/sorting-for-humans-natural-sort-order/) for a long rant about this, and some nice links to implementations of this natural algorithm. Just as a warning, the *correct* implementation (as opposed to the hacky answer you've accepted) is quite complicated, so don't try to implement it yourself, take someone else's (hopefully public domain or liberally licensed) implementation and use that instead.